# How do I build an element dynamically from a string name in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following code:

```
interface StyledTypographyProps extends TypographyProps {
    overrides?: { Typography: React.ComponentType };
}

export const StyledTypography: React.FunctionComponent<StyledTypographyProps> = (props) => {
    const { children, overrides, ...typographyProps } = props;

    const CustomTypography = overrides ?? MainTypography;

    return (
        <CustomTypography ref={ref} {...typographyProps}>
            {children}
        </CustomTypography>
    )
}
```

and I get the following error: `JSX element type 'CustomTypography' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: Could you post the complete code, including the implementation of the `<StyledTypography />` component? The first thing I've noticed is that the `overrides` uses an Object notation, this is not a valid React Component so you should either destructure it or declare the component directly in the `overrides` prop.

Comment: `overrides` doesn't appear to be a React component. It is an object with a property `Typography` which is a component.